# Nginx returns 404 after loggin in with basic authentication

Tags: nginx, next.js, basic-authentication, nginx-location, nginx-config

I've created a website with next.js and after deployment in my own test server , everything worked as expected.As there is and admin Area, i made a configuration to protect the `/admin` `url` using nginx basic auth.Here are my steps:

1. First i've installed the `apache2-utils` using `sudo apt-get install apache2-utils` on `Ubuntu 18.04`
2. I've created my credentials by running: `htpasswd /etc/nginx/.htpasswd myusername` .After click on `enter`, i've provided a `password`
3. I tried view the file content and everythinh was good because i've seen `usename:hashedpassword`
4. I made the following configuration in `nginx`

   `location /admin {
   auth_basic "Zone protege";
   auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
   }`

Here is my full configuration for that app.But i've hidden other configuration details(TLS,http redirect,etc..) :

```
 server {
    server_name mydomainename.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }


    location /admin {
        auth_basic "Zone protege";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
      } 
}
```

When i try to access the protected page,i get this :
[image: Login Popup]

When i tap bad credentials i don't get the request page as expected.

So when i tap the expected credentials i get a `404`:
[image: 404 Error]

I've already read the follwing solutions:
[NGINX auth_basic is giving me a '404 not found' message ...](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/nginx-auth_basic-is-giving-me-a-404-not-found-message)
[NGINX htpasswd 404 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55044955/nginx-htpasswd-404-not-found)

A tried other solutions as well even thaugh they aren't marked as solving the problem.

Comment: replace http://localhost:3000 with http://localhost:3001 and set up a netcat server syntax `nc -l -p 3001` for the original Hobbit's netcat, or `nc -l 3001` for BSD/MacOS netcat (those are common implementations at least) , then login on firefox, what do you get in the netcat server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ?

```
server {
    server_name mydomainename.com;
    auth_basic "Zone protege";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    location / {
        auth_basic off;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /admin {
        #auth_basic on;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    } 
}
```